# "... in summer in Australia". Is it right?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

I have this sentence:

> Although Christmas season is in summer in Australia, many Australians...

What I'm not sure about is the ***in Australia*** part. It's an adverbial, isn't it? An adverbial of place can be switched between the beginning and the end of the sentence, so is my sentence grammartically correct? Thank you.

Comment: Your sentence is grammatically correct.

Comment: Does it have the same meaning when I switch **in Australia** part to the beginning (in Australia, Christmas season is in summer...)?

Comment: I wouldn't gamble that ' An adverbial of place can be switched between the beginning and the end of the sentence' is sound for all sentences.

Comment: I would argue that it's modifying "Christmas season".

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, your sentence is grammatically correct.

However, if you switch the "In Australia" part to the beginning of the sentence, you can not join the following subject into one sentence.

It would be:

> In Australia, Christmas season is in summer. Many Australians...

Comment: So that means I can't use the **although** word? And my sentence is correct right? Because you type **is**, so I don't know you means **is** or **isn't**?

Comment: You can have "Although, in Australia, Christmas season ...".